# Remove attributes from xml string

Tags: php, xml, string

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-enc="" xmlns:soap-env="">
    <soap-env:header>
    </soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body>
        <ns1:createuserresponse>
            <username>weqew_825</username>
            <password>uwnoqedcjs</password>
            <result>
                <succeeded>true</succeeded>
                <errorcode>0</errorcode>
                <errortext></errortext>
            </result>
        </ns1:createuserresponse>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

I want to remove  `xmlns:soap-enc="" xmlns:soap-env=""` from above string

Comment: `str_replace` will do but note that without the NS declarations your XML will be invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/xmlns:.*\"/','',$string);
```

BUT it would be better to avoid that since again parsing that xml with SimpleXML will generate a lot of warnings (which could be surpressed with @).

a more solid solution

- [Parse XML with namespace using simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)
- [PHP: How to process SOAP response to get a tag value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927849/php-how-to-process-soap-response-to-get-a-tag-value)

hope it helped

Comment: simplexml_load_string is not converting above string to array that's why i want to remove that attributes